# Passing a parameter back to a view after performing a form action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have a view that loads a record with a certain record number. Once the page is loaded, it gives the user an opportunity to login for additional information. Once the login logic is performed, I need to return to that same view with the same record number intact. I am passing the record number to the action using a hidden input in the form. What I can't seem to figure out is how to return to that same view and provide it with that record #. The code I am trying below is not working. I know this is MVC 101 stuff but a hint in the right direction would be appreciated, or feel free to scrap my method and suggest something better!

Form in view:

```
 <form action="/MyView/Authenticate/@item.ID" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input name="form_id" type="hidden" value="@item.ID">
      .....
```

Form action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Authenticate()
    {
        int myid = Convert.ToInt16(Request["form_id"]);
        .....
        return View("Index",  new { id = myid } );
    }
```

EDIT:

It turns out that the correct view is being returned, but it is expecting a model item type of "JobSummaryModel" per the Index action result below. So the question I actually need answered is, how do I pass both the record id and this view model to it?

```
    public ActionResult Index(int id = 0)
    {
        List<JobSummaryModel> jdata;

        ViewBag.IsResults = false;

        if (id != 0)
        {
            ViewBag.IsResults = true;            
        }
        jdata = db.Jobs.Where(c => c.ID == id).Select(c => new JobSummaryModel() { ID = c.ID, Name = c.Name, City = c.City, PostalCode = c.PostalCode, JobDescription = c.PositionDescription }).ToList();
        return View(jdata);
    }
```

EDIT:

Thanks Reddy, your suggestions worked! My only remaining issue is that when I return to my Index view from the Authenticate action, I do not seem to have my "jdata". Is my Index action result not being rerun when I return the Index view via my Authenticate action? I am coming from a web forms background where, in an instance like this, the Load/Init events would automatically run when a form is loaded. Do I need to bind my "jdata" in the Authenticate action and include it in the viewmodel?

EDIT: Resolved. Changed my "return View" to a "return RedirectToAction" to resolve my final issue. Thanks everyone!

Comment: So is it returning to the correct view, but Id isn't correct?  Or is it going to the wrong view altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer For your after Edit:

All you want to pass to view is a `int Id` and your `List<JobSummaryModel> jdata` right?

So create a `ViewModel JObSummaryModelHelper`

```
Public class JObSummaryModelHelper
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public List<JobSummaryModel> jdata {get;set;}
}
```

Now in your controller

```
public ActionResult Index(int id = 0)
    {
        JObSummaryModelHelper jobDetails = new JObSummaryModelHelper();
        jobDetails.Id = id;           

        ViewBag.IsResults = false;

        if (id != 0)
        {
            ViewBag.IsResults = true;            
        }
        jobDetails .jdata = db.Jobs.Where(c => c.ID == id).Select(c => new JobSummaryModel() { ID = c.ID, Name = c.Name, City = c.City, PostalCode = c.PostalCode, JobDescription = c.PositionDescription }).ToList();
        return View(jobDetails );
    }
```

Now make sure your view is set to expect this new viewmodel

```
@model JObSummaryModelHelper
```

carry on with your manipulation......

Comment: Your answer contributed most to my solution. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are better off creating a ViewModel for this like so:

Create a View Model class i.e.

```
public class AuthViewModel
{
    public int MyId { get; set; }
}
```

In your View put the following directive at the top:

```
@model AuthViewModel
```

In your initial `[HttpGet]` method return the view model:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Authenticate()
{
    var model = new AuthViewModel { MyId = 123 };
    return View("Index", model );
}
```

It's best to use Html helpers in your view, so you can change it to this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MyId)
    ...
}
```

The above uses naming conventions to post back to the action that you are on.

Then return it to your view like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Authenticate(AuthViewModel model)
{
    int myid = model.MyId;
    return View("Index", model );
}
```

Then you can output using this razor syntax `@Model.MyId`

It's really worth doing some tutorials to learn the conventions, a small amount of time invested in this will save you a lot of time in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
return View("Index",  new { id = myid } );
```

could you do

```
return Index(myid);
```